# How to build an Android app as system service

Tags: java, android, android-service, android-source, android-framework

I am facing a problem with an app that is built to run as Android service and should start on boot without any user interaction or existing activity.

From other sources, we know that this is basically not possible: http://commonsware.com/blog/2011/07/13/boot-completed-regression-confirmed.html

Currently for testing purposes the application has a very simple GUI and it registers a broadcast receiver as follows:

```
public class MyAppReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver
{
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED.equals(intent.getAction())) {
            Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(context, MyAppService.class);
            context.startService(serviceIntent);
        }
    }
}
```

This works great if the user launches the app at least once in order to allow the receiver to get `ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED`.

The goal is to remove the GUI completely and yet have the application starting on boot without any action needed from the user. Note that this software **will not** be deployed on the Play Store but rather it's built to be part of a custom AOSP build not for public usage.

The only solution I found is to build the application as system service by adding it to the Android application framework.

See references:

http://www.androidenea.com/2009/12/adding-system-server-to-android.html
http://processors.wiki.ti.com/index.php/Android-Adding_SystemService

However I am a bit confused about the advantages and disadvantages of this possibility and I hope someone can answer the following questions:

**1)** Does the app need to be built with the whole system (AOSP from source) and therefore it cannot be deployed as APK?

**2)** Is there any way to update the application afterwards (with an APK) once the system has been built?

**3)** Is it even possible or convenient to run the app this way (as system service) purely because it needs to start on boot and not because of other reasons (such as instantiating code from it etc.)?

The app itself is nothing special - it's a client/remote-server model that reports system statistics for research purposes.

**EDIT**

Adding the manifest for completeness:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  package="org.myapp.myapp"
  android:versionCode="1"
  android:versionName="22.0">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_TASKS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

<application android:label="@string/app_name" android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher">

    <activity android:name="myapp"
              android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <service
        android:name="org.myapp.myappclient.myappservice"
        android:label="myappservice">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="org.myapp.myappclient.myappservice" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>

    <receiver
        android:enabled="true"
        android:name="org.myapp.myappclient.myappreceiver"
        android:permission="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

</application>
```

Comment: "Note that this software will not be deployed on the Play Store but rather it's built to be part of a custom AOSP build not for public usage." -- I would assume that apps that are pre-installed can be set up to be already moved out of the stopped state. If you buy an Android phone, and you look at the list of installed apps, there are many pre-loaded entries that are not "system services" yet work (e.g., "Basic Daydreams", "Certificate Installer", "Face Unlock", "Google Backup Transport", "Nfc Service", just to pick a few from the Nexus 4 that I have sitting here).

Comment: This is a very good point, I wasn't thinking about that. The app would have to be installed under /system/app in order to avoid users to uninstall it. I do build the whole system from source, however I don't yet know the best way to build apps in a non-stopped state. I will do more research!

Comment: Yeah, and I'm not enough of a system-level guy to know how you do that either. It's possible that merely being on the system partition is enough.

Answer (score 2):

If you are modifying AOSP You can create a "persistent app"

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/application-element#persistent

This goes on your application tag in the manifest

```
<application
  persistent="true"
  ...
>
```

> Whether or not the application should remain running at all times — "true" if it should, and "false" if not. The default value is "false". Applications should not normally set this flag; persistence mode is intended only for certain system applications.

It has to be a system app for it to work.

It will start on boot, any apps with this flag are started just before the `BOOT_COMPLETED` intent is fired from init.

Benefits being:

- It'll cause the app to be kept alive by the ActivityManager
- It'll be auto-magically restarted if the app dies
- The lifecycle changes won't result in your app closing

Then you can spawn services, or do whatever you want really.

I'm sure it won't help 5 years later, but might help someone else :-)

Answer (score 1):

1. In theory you should be able to deploy your apk separately but you may still have to modify the boot procedure to include your service to the list of programs/services to be launched.
2. Yes you can. Just make sure you use the same key to sign your application package.
3. This depends. Is it worth it to go down and modify the application framework just to make sure your service will function correctly in the event your user installs the app and then just leaves it? I guess you could include a release note somewhere to inform users that the app will not work until they run it at least once after installation.

***UPDATE***

1. Maybe you can get your Launcher app to take care of it then.
2. I think there is some confusion here. Pre-installed apps are not necessarily system apps. If your app does not require special permission, then it is just a pre-installed user app. Just think about that most phones ship with Facebook or Youtube and that those apps can be later updated.

Comment: 1. Do you think this would be in the init.rc? I do have a few services (ADB, SuperSU etc.) which are launched via init.rc but they all refer to Unix executables and I couldn't find much about how to run a Java application on boot. I suppose it would have to happen after Dalvik is loaded.
 
2. So it's possible to update system apps? That solves a lot of trouble!
 
3. Forgot to mention that the users are kids so I can't rely on their actions to run the app/service so really whatever it takes to get it working will do!

Answer (score 0):

1.No need to create a system service, just a normal service which run in background,you don't need GUI so don't use activity but service.
3. If make it as a system service ,when error occurred ,the whole system will be reset.

Comment: Thanks I didn't know about the behaviour of the OS when a system service crashes - it's definitely a downside. In response to 1. it looks like it wouldn't work without the user running the service at least once: http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidBroadcastReceiver/article.html#startingservices_alarmmanager

Comment: Is this <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>  in your AndroidManifest.xml ?

Comment: Yes it's in the manifest: I added the full XML to my original post.

Comment: "I am facing a problem with an app that is built to run as Android service and should start on boot without any user interaction or existing activity." since you don't need an activity, why not try using only service. And donot forget to revise the Android.mk and add the "LOCAL_CERTIFICATE := platform" .

Comment: OK, I can try to include the application without activity in the build source. Worth a try.

Comment: @bashintosh If your app is privileged and installed as part of an aosp image, it wont be uninstallable and it will be able to boot up before the user interacts with it. What you want will definitely work as a regular app. Also, as it will be an app, it will be updatable any way you want.